# Vpython: property 'axis' must be a vector

Tags: python, vpython

I am doing a Vpython assignment for my physics 2 class, which is asking to program the electric field of a dipole. I have written the following code:

```
## constants
oofpez = 9e9 # stands for One Over Four Pi Epsilon-Zero
qe = 1.6e-19  # postive charge value
s = 4e-11    # charge separation
R = 3e-10  # display Enet on a circle of radius R
scalefactor = 3e-20 # for scaling arrows to represent electric field

## objects
## Represent the two charges of the dipole by red and blue spheres:
plus = sphere(pos=vector(s/2,0,0), radius=1e-11, color=color.red)
qplus = qe   # charge of positive particle
neg = sphere(pos=vector(-s/2,0,0), radius=1e-11, color=color.blue)
qneg = -qplus  # charge of negative particle


## calculations
## You will complete the lines required to make a loop calculate and display the net dipole electric field
## at equally spaced angles on a circle radius R around the dipole. The dipole is centered at the origin.
theta = 0
while theta < 2*pi:
    rate(2)   # tell computer to go through loop slowly
    ## Calculate observation location (tail of arrow) using current value of theta:
    Earrow = arrow(pos=R*vector(cos(theta),sin(theta),0), axis=vector(1e-10,0,0), color=color.orange)
    ## assign the name TestLocation to be the observation location on the circle radius R
    TestLocation=R*vector(cos(theta),sin(theta),0)
    ## write instructions below to tell the computer how to calculate the correct 
    ## net electric field Enet at the observation location (the position of Earrow):
    rPlus=TestLocation-plus.pos
    rPlusMag=((R*cos(theta)-(s/2))^2+(R*sin(theta))^2)^0.5
    rPlusHat=rPlus/rPlusMag
    Eplus=oofpez*qplus/(rPlusMag)^2*rPlusHat

    rNeg=TestLocation-neg.pos
    rNegMag=((R*cos(theta)-(-s/2))^2+(R*sin(theta))^2)^0.5
    rNegHat=rNeg/rNegMag
    Eneg=oofpez*qneg/(rNegMag)^2*rNegHat

    Etotal=Eplus+Eneg

    Enet=arrow(pos=TestLocation,axis=Etotal*scalefactor, color=color.green)

    ## change the axis of Earrow to point in the direction of the electric field at that location
    ## and scale it so it looks reasonable
    ## Efield = arrow(pos=R*vector(cos(theta),sin(theta),0), axis=Etotal*scalefactor, color=color.blue)
    Earrow.axis=Etotal*scalefactor

    ## Assign a new value to theta
    theta = theta + pi/6
```

The assignment had a pre-made template created with the comments, the proper variables declared and said variables assigned the correct values, so in theory it should run correctly if I input the rest of the code correctly. The code I wrote starts at "rPlus=..." and ends at "Enet=..." However, when I run it (using GlowScript IDE) it gives an error message saying "Error: Property 'axis' must be a vector," which I'm sure means that there's something wrong with the value assigned to Enet.axis within that section of the code. I have looked through the code I've generated and can't seem to find the error.

We are learning python supplementary to our regular course work so I do not have any background in python besides these assignments. I don't need help with finding the electric field, just why the error message is popping up. Any help or hint in the right direction would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can  you post your complete error? To know exactly where the error originates from. I think the error might be on the line `Earrow.axis=Etotal*scalefactor` . VPython has  `vector` [object](http://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/vector.html) that needs to be used instead of arrays.

Comment: The full error only says "Error: Property 'axis' must be a vector." It unfortunately doesn't say which line it is on, but I'll go back and look at that line of code to double check.

Answer (score 0):

On line 31 you used ^ instead of ** for exponentiation.

If you use the Chrome browser you can get the line number of an error.

I found the problem by inserting print statements at key locations in the code, which turned up the fact that rPlusMag was 0, not a vector.